# Mongoid fields and subsequently added localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, mongoid3

Is there something to consider when I am adding localization later on?

from
    class Articles
    field :title, type: String
to
    class Articles
    field :title, type: String, localize: true

I have content on my `Articles` model and wanna add localization subsequently.

Now I found out that sometimes content will be shown as a hash

```
{"en"=>"asdfasdf", "de"=>"123123123"}
```

and sometimes as normal text.

If I show an Article via

```
@article.title
# I get --> no implicit conversion from nil to integer


@article.title_translations
# I get --> no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

This happens always if a document was not translated. (String).

## additional

Also if I try to alter the content I have problems:

```
article.title # "en"
article.title_translations # "Test Title"
article.update_attribute(:name, c.name_translations)
# raises NoMethodError: undefined method `merge!' for "Test Title":String
article.name = c.title_translations
# raises NoMethodError: undefined method `merge!' for "Test Title":String
```

## Question

- How to ALTER String fields to "String, :localize => true" correctly?
- Is there a script or something to mirgrate?

Comment: The documentation maybe can help you: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html (Localized fields section)

Comment: Not really, or do you mean a specific section in the manual. The manual only describes how to do that with "fresh" fields. But not on a migration like field type change. My DB is already filled with content.

Answer (score 4):

If a document was not translated and you try to access to this field, it raises an error:

```
no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

If you try to change it it raises an error:

```
raises NoMethodError: undefined method `merge!' for "Test Title":String
```

It seems a mongoid bug. For now, you can do this for migration after add 'localize: true':

```
I18n.locale = :en
Article.all.each do |article|
  begin
    article.title
  rescue
    b = article.attributes['title']
    article.unset('title')
    article.title = b
    article.save
  end
end
```

It made the trick for me.

Comment: thank you drinor. Durden offered me also an eye opener:
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3488

Answer (score 1):

Translations internally handled via a hash

```
{ "en" => "book", "de" => "Buch" }
```

I've got it working with

```
Article.each do |article|
  article.title_translations = {"en" => article.title_translations}
  article.save!
end
```

Thank you Mr. Durden:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3488

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the previous solutions raise exceptions, this is what I do:

```
Article.all.each do |article|
  value = article.attributes['title'].try(:clone)
  unless value.is_a?(Hash)
    Article.collection.where({ _id: article._id }).update({
      "$set" => {
        "title" => I18n.available_locales.inject({}) do |m, l|
           m[l.to_s] = v
           m
         end
      }
    })
  end
end
```